# Find add method of java.util.list via JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to find the "add" method of java.util.list. The method takes the input and return value type as follows:

```
jmethodID addMethodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, listClass, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object)(Ljava/lang/String)Z;");
```

return value is NULL. Where am I going wrong? Is the boolean specification of the output wrong or is it the input type? Should I specify my input type? If so, how?

Comment: Don't try to build JNI signatures yourself. Use the output of javap -s. It is never wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.util.List.add(Object e) only has one argument... you have two listed (object and string) and a return type. I think you want:   (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z;

Comment: add method returns boolean. Does 'Z' represent boolean? I read somewhere that boolean has to be casted to String.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page on JNI](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html).

In your code I think you are missing some semi-colons from your method signature. That is: `"(Ljava/lang/Object)(Ljava/lang/String)Z;"` should be `"(Ljava/lang/Object;)(Ljava/lang/String;)Z;"`.

You could look into using [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) with the `-s` flag to automatically generate the signatures for the desired methods.

Comment: I tried, not working.
The list is of a custom object called Node. I tried using "(Ljava/lang/Object;)(Ljava/lang/String;)Z;" and "(LNode;)(Ljava/lang/String;)Z;". Both arent working

Comment: Did you try using javap to generate the signature for you? And what is the namespace of your custom Node object?

Comment: Node class is in the same package, if thats what you mean. how do i invoke javap for list? The "add" method I am referring to is in hava.util.list and it doesn't get listed in javap output for the class I am looking at

Comment: I added a new add method in my class to use javap. Seems to work on invoking the new add method.

Comment: Regardless of whether `Node` is in the same package or not it should still be fully qualified.